# Skills for mastering old music

Tags: mixing, mastering

There is a new store in town that sells old music (1910s and onward), and while I find it enjoyable, the quality is generally poor.

I have long wanted to learn how to work with audio, and this is kind of a good excuse to get into it. As a hobby, I want to work with this old audio to practice working with audio.

I am new to this, so what sets of skills should I work on specifically for this?

### Update

The thing I want to begin with is removing noise from the recordings. The kind of noise I am talking about is the same as in, for instance, this collection:
https://archive.org/details/BillyJonesErnestHare

Comment: depending on what you want 'practice working with audio', this is a very specific subset of audio examples. nowadays audio quality is much better and as a result 'editing' or 'mastering' audio is a very high skilled and technical affair. although it is a nice place to start, i would recommend doing a course in audio engineering basics. after that you'll probably know much better what you want dive into deeper. that said: do take a shot at restoring the audio quality, but keep in mind there's more out there! :)

Comment: Yeah, maybe... I will however make my question more specific to get more answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a nice video to take a grasp of how remix is done.(If this is a kind of remix you mean) You'll need a lot of knowledge on using specific programs like sequencers and plugins.

If you meant you want to improve the sound quality, then you mean 'remastering', and you can get the idea of it in this video.

Remastering generally requires extremely acute audio hearing skills and expensive machines.

Comment: Yeah, I meant mastering. I'll edit my question.